# How to solve the matrix equation AX-XA=BX+XB+C

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

I know that $$AX+XB=C $$ is equal to $$(B^T⊕A)vec(X)=vec(C)$$
Now i don't know if i can use it here like: $$AX-XA-BX-XB=C$$
$$vec(AX-XA-BX-XB)=vec(X)$$ $$ vec(AX-XB)-vec(BX+XA)=vec(X)$$ $$(-B^T⊕A)vec(X)-(A^T⊕B)vec(X)$$ $$ [(-B^T⊕A)-(A^T⊕B)]vec(x)=vec(C)$$

Comment: Your claim is wrong. $AX+XB$, in matrix-vector form, is not equal to $(B^T\oplus A)\operatorname{vec}(X)$ (the dimensions are not right in the first place), but $(I\otimes A+B^T\otimes I)\operatorname{vec}(X)$. Anyway, this can be rewritten as $(B-A)X+X(B+A)=-C$, which is just another [Sylvester equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester_equation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $L_A$ and $R_A$ are the operators $X \to AX$ and $X \to XA$ respectively (linear operators on the vector space of $n \times n$ matrices), your equation is 
$$ (L_A - R_A - L_B - R_B) X = C $$
You'll have a solution if and only if $C$ is in the range of $L_A - R_A - L_B - R_B$.  In particular, this is the case for all $C$ if $L_A - R_A - L_B - R_B$ is invertible.  You can represent $L_A$ and $R_A$ as the Kronecker products $A \otimes I$ and $I \otimes A$ respectively.